# How to improve my regression testing speed

Tags: testing

I find myself running my application quite often from the IDE, testing a lot of simpler changes and I find it bogs down my development time but if I don't I'm afraid of bugs creeping up from previous dependent work. In larger product environment where it can take minutes to build - how often does everyone realistically test? How do you cope with potentially faulty code?

Comment: I generally try to adhere to [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) principles as much as I can with unit tests. If you're using eclipse, plugins like [MoreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/) and [Infinitest](http://infinitest.github.com/) are good helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things that I do:

- Code defensively:

  - Use asserts liberally to test assumptions (can always turn asserts off for production code: although there are companies that ship code with assertions turn on to make diagnosing problem behaviour easier - even for up to ~30% overhead)
  - Mutual suspicion: always validate input to a unit before you use it
  - Whitelist instead of blacklist: it's usually easier to specify what constitutes as "valid" behaviour than trying to enumerate all the ways something can fail.
- Code Review:

  - Use of code review process through open source software such as ReviewBoard has been shown to improve overall development speed / quality.
- Smoke testing: simple, inexpensive tests to check basic assumptions / behaviour before moving on to the longer tests - this can save you a lot of time.
- Unit testing:

  - Include self-contained tests for each unit of code that you write: a block of code, a function/method, a class, a package... and so on
  - As soon as the smallest block of code you write can be tested, test it - it will save you time down the line.
  - Utilize a a testing framework to run these together automatically
- Regression testing:

  - Test everything after changes go in to make sure nothing breaks. These typically take longer to run, so you may have to do these on nightly builds.
- Write tests before you write the code:

  - Writing tests first helps you understand exactly what the program is supposed to do / behave.
  - It helps you code exactly to specifications

Answer (score 0):

Automating regression testing is one of the best investments you can make to improve your development speed.

This is the area where you should be working smarter not harder. There is a tonne of published information on Automated Testing. You should be doing it this way wherever possible.

Examples range from data testing, through unit testing to integration and UI testing. All of these can be automated to some degree to make your life easier. There are too many tools and practises to list but I used to use a site http://www.opensourcetesting.org/resources.php that could be an entry point for you. Also there are lot so questions on SO about these topics.